# Mailchimp merge tags in Google Analytics measurement protocol hit URLs

Tags: email, google-analytics, mailchimp, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics measurement protocol to send a hit to GA when someone opens an email from Mailchimp. The documentation I'm following is here: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/

I'd like to use Mailchimp merge tags to insert dynamic values for some of the parameters. For example:

- client id --> be cid=*|UNIQID|*
- event label --> el=*|MC:SUBJECT|*

An example of pixel code placed at the end of an email:

> img
>   src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXX-Y&cid=*|UNIQID|*&t=event&ec=Email&ea=open&el=*|MC:SUBJECT|*&cm=email&cs=*|LIST:NAME|*&cn=*|CAMPAIGN_UID|*&cc=teaser2&cm1=1"

In GA, none of the merge tag values are showing up. The client ID is  "*|UNIQID|*" instead of a dynamically inserted value and the event label is "(not set)".